# How can I subtract like end_date - start_date in django template

Tags: django

I'd like to subtract date in template but don't know how.

is there any way to subtract two column in django template?

**template.html**

```
                {% for career in careers %}
                    {% if career.user == user%}
                    <div class="flex">
                        <div class="w-1/4">
                            <p class="font-thin">{{career.job}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w-1/4">
                            <p class="font-thin">{{career.company}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w-1/4">
                            <p class="font-thin">{{career.position}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w-1/4">
                            <p class="font-thin">{{career.end_date}}-{{career.start_date}}</p> //as clearly, it doesn't work.
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this with `@property` function in `models.py`

in `models.py`

```
class <YourClassName>(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def get_duration(self):
        dt = self.end_date - self.start_date
        # with dt you can get days and seconds and you can covert or format in week or hours whatever you want
        return dt.days # returns number of days
```

then in template simply use

```
{{career.get_duration}}
```